# Postfix configuration with antispam

Tags: postfix

I have postfix with anti spam and when anti spam returns status 554 (spam mail) to postfix the mail is bounced to the sender.

Is there a way to decide another action for postfix for 554 like reject.

And another question is:
is it possible to look for the domain of the sender and decide if to bounce or to reject according to the domain (look in some list of domains).

Thanks.

Comment: What anti-spam solution are you now using and how exactly did you configure Postfix to use it? Perhaps Spampd/Spamassassin/DSPAM hooked into Postfix with `content_filter`? Please copy/paste your configuration files in your question ([edit] it). That way we can help you better.

Comment: Sounds like it's easier and more helpful for everybody if you'd ask two questions.

Comment: Yes I use it with content_filter=..
Does it matter what anti spam it is? isn't it depends on postfix configuration only ?